# UITableViewCell Borders Change When tableView.reloadData() is called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Very confused about what is happening with my `UITableViewCell` when `reloadData` is called. When the tableview first loads, each cell has its correct rounding. The top has its top corners rounded, the middle has no rounding, and the bottom has only its bottom.

Here is what it looks like on first load:
[image: First Load Cells]

Here is what happens if a `tableview.reloadData` is called (1 or more times)
[image: Subsequent reloads]

Here is the code where the cells are created `(in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath))`

```swift
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell().reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.roundCorners(corners: (top: true, bottom: false))
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.roundCorners(corners: (top: false, bottom: false))
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            cell.roundCorners(corners: (top: false, bottom: true))
        }
```

Here is the code for the rounded corners:

```swift
    func roundCorners(corners: (top: Bool, bottom: Bool)) {
        if !corners.top && !corners.bottom {
            roundCorners(withRadius: 0)
        } else if corners.top && corners.bottom {
           roundCorners(withRadius: 20)
        } else if corners.top {
            roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
        } else if corners.bottom {
            roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)
        }
    }

// and the actual rounding methods

    func roundCorners() {
        roundCorners(withRadius: bounds.size.height * 0.5)
    }

    func roundCorners(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }

    func maskedCorners(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func maskedCorners(corners: CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {
        layer.maskedCorners = corners
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

I have tried several things which did not work.

1. Instead of reusing cells (I thought maybe the way they were being reused was mucking with the draw calls), I tried instantiating the cell each time
2. I tried resetting the cell borders to 0 and then setting which corners should be rounded
3. I tried calling the .setNeedsDisplay() after updating the borders

I will also note that if I comment out the rounding calls, no rounding occurs at all, so the issue is strictly isolated to the code above.

Very open to suggestions as to why after the first reloadData() call it rounds the middle cell and keeps it rounded moving forward.

Comment: i tried this with custom cell and even after reloadData it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues...

1 - you're using `bounds` before the cell's layout is complete, so `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, ...)` can be wrong.

2 - in this code:

```
func roundCorners(corners: (top: Bool, bottom: Bool)) {
    if !corners.top && !corners.bottom {
        // NOT setting a layer mask
        roundCorners(withRadius: 0)
    } else if corners.top && corners.bottom {
        // NOT setting a layer mask
        roundCorners(withRadius: 20)
    } else if corners.top {
        // YES setting a layer mask
        roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
    } else if corners.bottom {
        // YES setting a layer mask
        roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)
    }
}
```

cells are reused, so you can get a cell used for the First or Last row - where the layer mask is set - then it gets used as a "middle" row and the layer mask ***is not cleared***.

So, either clear the mask for the "middle" rows (`layer.mask = nil`), or ***always*** call the func that uses the mask:

```
func roundCorners(corners: (top: Bool, bottom: Bool)) {
    if !corners.top && !corners.bottom {
        roundCorners(corners: [], radius: 0)
    } else if corners.top && corners.bottom {
        roundCorners(corners: [], radius: 20)
    } else if corners.top {
        roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
    } else if corners.bottom {
        roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Here's some sample code that you *might* find makes things a bit more manageable...

**Cell Class**

```
class RoundedCornersCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    enum CornerStyle {
        case solo, top, middle, bottom
    }
    
    public var cornerStyle: CornerStyle = .middle {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var theCorners: UIRectCorner = []
        switch cornerStyle {
        case .solo:
            theCorners = .allCorners
        case .top:
            theCorners = [.topLeft, .topRight]
        case .bottom:
            theCorners = [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
        case .middle:
            ()
        }
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: theCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }

}
```

**Example Controller Class**

```
class ExampleTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    var myData: [Int] = []
    var shuffledData: [Int]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        myData = Array(1...5)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(RoundedCornersCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "rcc")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        shuffledData = myData
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shuffledData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rcc", for: indexPath) as! RoundedCornersCell
        
        // if there's only one row
        if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) == 1 {
            c.cornerStyle = .solo
        } else {
            c.cornerStyle =
            indexPath.row == 0 ? .top
            : indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 ? .bottom
            : .middle
        }

        c.textLabel?.text = "\(shuffledData[indexPath.row])"
        return c
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        shuffledData = myData.shuffled()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant deduction and explanation. Thank you very very much

Comment: @Aggressor - I added some example code that (may) make your life a little easier. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For such layout you don't have to code instead you can use tableview style `Inset Grouped`.

Just go to your `Storyboard settings` > `Table attribute inspector` > `Style` > Select `Inset Grouped`:

[image: table view settings]

**And here's the output:**

[image: output]

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, appreciated. I still don't know the root of the problem but this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can round corners of the tableView:

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```